# ScrollBar для RecyclerView, по типу как в галереи

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать такой быстрый ScrollBar для RecyclerView, как часто встречаются в галереях? Может кто библиотеку хорошую подскажет, именно такую, похожую как на фото?

[image: ScrollBar :]

Comment: Просто добавь вместо LinearLayout Manager GridLayout в аргументы передай нужное количество столбцов

Comment: Не очень понял, нужен такой ScrollBar как на рисунке, чтобы можно было быстро прокручивать RecyclerView.. То что я видел примеры FastScrollBar, немного не те.. Где взять сам ScrollBar такой?

Comment: Значит я не так понял вопрос